# Flexbox how to have child elements fill the height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zvdvd067/) example here.  What I'm trying to do is have the right side `.inside-right` fill the height of `.right`.  You can see the black background is only taking up a small space at the top.  I've tried various heights `100%`, `auto`, but can't seem to get it to fill all the way.  Any suggestions would be great!

```css
    .container {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row;
    }
 
    .container > .field {
        width: 100%;
        background: #dddd88;
        order: 2;
    }

    .container > .left {
        width: 4px;
        background: #ccccff;
        order: 1;
    }
  
    .container > .right {
        width: 4px;
        background: #ccccff;
        order: 3;
    }
 
    .top, .bottom {
        display: block;
        height: 4px;
        background: red;
    }
    
    .inside-right {
      background: black;
      width: 4px;
     }
```

```html
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="field">
    Main Body
    <br><br><br>
  </div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right">
      <div class="inside-right">
        -
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="bottom"></div>



<span></span>
```

Comment: You should post your code in the question itself.

Comment: And a simple solution is to add `display: flex` to `.right`. The forces the child to take full height (based on the `align-items: stretch` default).

Comment: By simply add `height: 100%` to the `.inside-right` works perfectly fine: https://jsfiddle.net/2oc54fc6/

Comment: Update the code within the question and you'll get 2 good answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to do it is make `.right` `display: flex` and by default, the children (or child, in this case) will `stretch` to fill the height of the parent.

```css
    .container {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row;
    }
 
    .container > .field {
        width: 100%;
        background: #dddd88;
        order: 2;
    }

    .container > .left {
        width: 4px;
        background: #ccccff;
        order: 1;
    }
  
    .container > .right {
        width: 4px;
        background: #ccccff;
        order: 3;
        display: flex;
    }
 
    .top, .bottom {
        display: block;
        height: 4px;
        background: red;
    }
    
    .inside-right {
      background: black;
      width: 4px;
     }
```

```html
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="field">
    Main Body
    <br><br><br>
  </div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right">
      <div class="inside-right">
        -
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="bottom"></div>



<span></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add a `min-height`

```
.inside-right {
  background: black;
  width: 4px;
  min-height:100%;
 }
```

complete working code:

```css
    .container {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row;
    }
 
    .container > .field {
        width: 100%;
        background: #dddd88;
        order: 2;
    }

    .container > .left {
        width: 4px;
        background: #ccccff;
        order: 1;
    }
  
    .container > .right {
        width: 4px;
        background: #ccccff;
        order: 3;
    }
 
    .top, .bottom {
        display: block;
        height: 4px;
        background: red;
    }
    
    .inside-right {
      background: black;
      width: 4px;
   min-height:100%;
     }
```

```html
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="field">
    Main Body
    <br><br><br>
  </div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right">
      <div class="inside-right">
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="bottom"></div>



<span></span>
```

working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zvdvd067/1/) here